# How to override a value from slingshot.properties in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I am using alfresco 6. I have created custom xml and a custom properties file under web-extension folder. My changes are not getting reflected. What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to place the custom-slingshot properties file under web-extension\messages folder and you need to create & place the custom-slingshot context file to import the custom-slingshot properties file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>
<beans>
  <bean id="org_alfresco_module_custom_propertyBootstrap" class="org.alfresco.i18n.ResourceBundleBootstrapComponent">
      <property name="resourceBundles">
         <list>
            <value>alfresco.web-extension.messages.customslingshot</value>
         </list>
      </property>
   </bean>   
</beans>
```

Save this as, **custom-slingshot-application-context.xml** file under web-extension folder.

Create **customslingshot.properties under web-extension\messages** and override the message in customslingshot.properties file.

Hope this helps

Note: This is working on Alfresco 5.x and it should work with Alfresco 6.0. Please let me know,if you face any issues.